# How can I additionally optimize Cython code?

Tags: python, optimization, cython

I am currently translating a Python program for evaluating the [Wasserstein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric) into Cython. The goal is to make it as fast as possible to compute. My current approach already decreased runtime by quite a bit; however, I am new to Cython, so probably I have missed some optimization opportunities.

The code of the program is as follows:

```
#cython: language_level=3
cimport cython
import numpy as np
from numpy cimport ndarray, float64_t, uint32_t
from libc.math cimport sqrt, fabs

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cdef float64_t move_supply(
        ndarray[float64_t, ndim=2] supply,
        ndarray[float64_t, ndim=2] capacity,
        (uint32_t, uint32_t) from_index,
        (uint32_t, uint32_t) to_index,
):
    cdef float64_t flow, distance
    if supply[from_index] <= capacity[to_index]:
        flow = supply[from_index]
        capacity[to_index] = capacity[to_index]-flow
        supply[from_index] = <float64_t>0.0
    else:
        flow = capacity[to_index]
        supply[from_index] = supply[from_index]-flow
        capacity[to_index] = <float64_t>0.0
    distance = sqrt(fabs(from_index[0]-to_index[0])**2 + fabs(from_index[1]-to_index[1])**2)
    return flow*distance

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef (uint32_t, uint32_t) find_first_candidate(ndarray[float64_t, ndim=2] array, int hist_shape):
    cdef uint32_t ie, je
    cdef (uint32_t, uint32_t) neg_return = (-1, -1)
    for ie in range(hist_shape):
        for je in range(hist_shape):
            if array[ie][je] > <float64_t>0.0:
                return ie, je
    return neg_return

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef float64_t wasserstein_distance(
        ndarray[float64_t, ndim=2] supply,
        ndarray[float64_t, ndim=2] capacity,
        int hist_shape,
):
    cdef float64_t score = 0.0
    cdef uint32_t i, j
    cdef (uint32_t, uint32_t) from_index, to_index
    cdef (uint32_t, uint32_t) neg = (-1, -1)


    for i in range(hist_shape):
        from_index = find_first_candidate(supply, hist_shape)
        for j in range(hist_shape):
            to_index = find_first_candidate(capacity, hist_shape)
            if from_index == neg or to_index  == neg:
                return score
            work = move_supply(supply, capacity, from_index, to_index)
            score += work
    return score

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cpdef ndarray[float64_t, ndim=2] calculate_novelty(ndarray[float64_t, ndim=3] histograms):
    cdef uint32_t i, j
    cdef uint32_t amount_instances = histograms.shape[0], histogram_size = histograms.shape[1]
    cdef ndarray[float64_t, ndim=1] novelty_scores = np.zeros(amount_instances, dtype=np.float64)

    for i in range(amount_instances-1):
        for j in range(i+1, amount_instances):
            score = wasserstein_distance(histograms[i].copy(), histograms[j].copy(), histogram_size)
            novelty_scores[i] += score
            novelty_scores[j] += score
    return novelty_scores
```

I was thinking of using `prange` somehow, but I am unsure how to use it properly in the context of this program.

The function would be called with a `np.ndarray` with shape (a, s, s).
*a* being the amount of histograms. *s* being the size of a histogram in x/y dimensions.

Comment: Can you give an example of how this code would be called?

Comment: You might find it helpful to read how [scipy implements Wasserstein Distance](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.11.3/scipy/stats/_stats_py.py#L9896). They seem to have chosen a different algorithm which involves sorting both distributions first, which lets them avoid searching all pairs of values. Unsure if this is faster than your approach.

Comment: @NickODell I added a quick explanation of what is used to call the function.  I hope this is helpful. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: `array[ie][je]` - it's possibly that might end up pretty bad - it strictly asks for a slice, then an index of a slice. It's possible that Cython might optimize through that, but `array[ie, je]` is definitely right.

Comment: The `fabs` are not needed because f the squares. Multiple `sqrt` can be computed in at once with SIMD instructions. That being said, I expect the algorithm to be the main issue. There are too many loops causing the complexity to be pretty bad.